# Getting a random number without the Random library

Tags: java, dll, random

I would like to get random numbers between a range I give, but the problem I don't want to use the Random library of Java or anything I have to initializate.

Does anyone know an alternative way to get random numbers without using the java library?

Thanks

EDIT: What do you think about this solution?

```
   int random = i + (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()%((j - i) + 1));
```

Where i and j are the range

Comment: I haven't said that. I'm saying that I don't want to initializate anything to do THIS.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: Simplest is to get some time value (eg, System.nanoTime) and hash it up.  Not necessarily real random, but maybe the best you can do.

Comment: (But maybe you should reveal why you want the random numbers, and what size/range of numbers you need.  A RNG for a game is much different from an RNG for a security system.)

Comment: Yeah, it's for a videogame. It doesn't really have to be really accurated.

Comment: So why can't you use the class files that I provided?

Comment: -1 for not using the built-in tools for exactly the purpose they're meant.

Comment: [This](http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~irjohnso/coursenotes/ufeen8-15-m/p1192-parkmiller.pdf) is a good (perhaps "classic") article on the topic that give some decent yet simple RNG algorithms.  Probably not "current" given modern security issues, but more than adequate for a game.  The algorithms are all of about 10 lines long.  The only tricky thing is assuring that you're getting the correct modulo arithmetic on your target platform.

Comment: 1) What is "f".  2) I think it would be better to use nanoTime().

Comment: I wrote it wrong. i and j are the range in where the random number moves. Yeah, I think it would be better with nanoTime

Comment: You keep using that word...I don't think it means what you think it means.

Comment: which one? If you don't say it to me I'll never know

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your own pseudo-random number generation algorithm, which is literally reinventing the wheel and will not be secure!

Another solution is to use a service that generates true random numbers [like Random.org](http://www.random.org/)

Comment: I don't think it's that difficult. I thought using the system current time, but I couldn't make it works.

Comment: Are you talking about the seed that you use to initialize  the random number generation?

Answer (score 1):

I learned that the best method for generating the most random numbers is using the Mersenne Twister random number generator. This generator will provide you with enough random numbers to not need to reseed, it has a period of (2^19937) − 1

Here is source code for MerseeneTwister

https://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Natural-Language-Processing/MorphAdorner/edu/northwestern/at/utils/math/randomnumbers/MersenneTwister.java.htm

Here is a class to generate your random numbers.

```
class RandomVariable {

/** Initialize Mersenne Twister generator. */
private static MersenneTwister rnd = new MersenneTwister();

public static double rand() {
    return rnd.nextDouble();
}

/** Generate a random number from a uniform random variable.
 *
 *  @param  min Mininum value for the random variable.
 *  @param  max Maximum value for the random variable.
 *
 *  @return     A random double between min and max.
 */
public static double uniform(double min, double max) {
    return min + (max - min) * rand();
}
}
```

Here is a sample to generate a random number. Please note that I removed the comments from the source. This may voliate the open source nature of the code, but I couldnt copy it all and have it formated as code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class sample{
public static void main(String args[]){
    RandomVariable gen = new RandomVariable();
    double num = gen.uniform(-1,1);

    int n = 10000;
    Set<Double> nums = new HashSet<Double>();
    while (numbers.size() < n)
        nums.add(gen.uniform(-1,1));

}
}
class RandomVariable {

/** Initialize Mersenne Twister generator. */
private static MersenneTwister rnd = new MersenneTwister();

public static double rand() {
    return rnd.nextDouble();
}

/** Generate a random number from a uniform random variable.
 *
 *  @param  min Mininum value for the random variable.
 *  @param  max Maximum value for the random variable.
 *
 *  @return     A random double between min and max.
 */
public static double uniform(double min, double max) {
    return min + (max - min) * rand();
}
}

class MersenneTwister extends java.util.Random implements Serializable {
// Period parameters

private static final int N = 624;
private static final int M = 397;
private static final int MATRIX_A = 0x9908b0df;   // private static final 
//* constant vector a
private static final int UPPER_MASK = 0x80000000; // most significant 
//   w-r bits
private static final int LOWER_MASK = 0x7fffffff; // least significant 
//  r bits
// Tempering parameters
private static final int TEMPERING_MASK_B = 0x9d2c5680;
private static final int TEMPERING_MASK_C = 0xefc60000;
private int mt[]; // the array for the state vector
private int mti; // mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized
private int mag01[];
// a good initial seed (of int size, though stored in a long)
// private static final long GOOD_SEED = 4357;

/* implemented here because there's a bug in Random's implementation
of the Gaussian code (divide by zero, and log(0), ugh!), yet its
gaussian variables are private so we can't access them here.  :-( */
private double __nextNextGaussian;
private boolean __haveNextNextGaussian;

/**
 * Constructor using the default seed.
 */
public MersenneTwister() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

/**
 * Constructor using a given seed.  Though you pass this seed in
 * as a long, it's best to make sure it's actually an integer.
 */
public MersenneTwister(final long seed) {
    super(seed);    /* just in case */
    setSeed(seed);
}

/**
 * Constructor using an array.
 */
public MersenneTwister(final int[] array) {
    super(System.currentTimeMillis());
    /* pick something at random just in case */
    setSeed(array);
}

/**
 * Initalize the pseudo random number generator.  Don't
 * pass in a long that's bigger than an int (Mersenne Twister
 * only uses the first 32 bits for its seed).
 */
synchronized public void setSeed(final long seed) {
    // it's always good style to call super
    super.setSeed(seed);

    // Due to a bug in java.util.Random clear up to 1.2, we're
    // doing our own Gaussian variable.
    __haveNextNextGaussian = false;

    mt = new int[N];

    mag01 = new int[2];
    mag01[0] = 0x0;
    mag01[1] = MATRIX_A;

    mt[0] = (int) (seed & 0xfffffff);
    for (mti = 1; mti < N; mti++) {
        mt[mti] =
                (1812433253 * (mt[mti - 1] ^ (mt[mti - 1] >>> 30)) + mti);

        /* See Knuth TAOCP Vol2. 3rd Ed. P.106 for multiplier. */

        /* In the previous versions, MSBs of the seed affect   */

        /* only MSBs of the array mt[].                        */

        /* 2002/01/09 modified by Makoto Matsumoto             */
        mt[mti] &= 0xffffffff;

        /* for >32 bit machines */
    }
}

/**
 * An alternative, more complete, method of seeding the
 * pseudo random number generator.  array must be an
 * array of 624 ints, and they can be any value as long as
 * they're not *all* zero.
 */
synchronized public void setSeed(final int[] array) {
    int i, j, k;

    setSeed(19650218);
    i = 1;
    j = 0;
    k = (N > array.length ? N : array.length);
    for (; k != 0; k--) {
        mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i - 1] ^ (mt[i - 1] >>> 30)) * 1664525))
                + array[j] + j; /* non linear */
        mt[i] &= 0xffffffff; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
        i++;
        j++;
        if (i >= N) {
            mt[0] = mt[N - 1];
            i = 1;
        }
        if (j >= array.length) {
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    for (k = N - 1; k != 0; k--) {
        mt[i] = (mt[i] ^ ((mt[i - 1] ^ (mt[i - 1] >>> 30)) * 1566083941))
                - i; /* non linear */
        mt[i] &= 0xffffffff; /* for WORDSIZE > 32 machines */
        i++;
        if (i >= N) {
            mt[0] = mt[N - 1];
            i = 1;
        }
    }
    mt[0] = 0x80000000; /* MSB is 1; assuring non-zero initial array */
}

/**
 * Returns an integer with <em>bits</em> bits filled with a random number.
 */
synchronized protected int next(final int bits) {
    int y;

    if (mti >= N) // generate N words at one time
    {
        int kk;
        final int[] mt = this.mt; // locals are slightly faster
        final int[] mag01 = this.mag01; // locals are slightly faster

        for (kk = 0; kk < N - M; kk++) {
            y = (mt[kk] & UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk + 1] & LOWER_MASK);
            mt[kk] = mt[kk + M] ^ (y >>> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
        }
        for (; kk < N - 1; kk++) {
            y = (mt[kk] & UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk + 1] & LOWER_MASK);
            mt[kk] = mt[kk + (M - N)] ^ (y >>> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
        }
        y = (mt[N - 1] & UPPER_MASK) | (mt[0] & LOWER_MASK);
        mt[N - 1] = mt[M - 1] ^ (y >>> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];

        mti = 0;
    }

    y = mt[mti++];
    y ^= y >>> 11;                          // TEMPERING_SHIFT_U(y)
    y ^= (y << 7) & TEMPERING_MASK_B;       // TEMPERING_SHIFT_S(y)
    y ^= (y << 15) & TEMPERING_MASK_C;      // TEMPERING_SHIFT_T(y)
    y ^= (y >>> 18);                        // TEMPERING_SHIFT_L(y)

    return y >>> (32 - bits);    // hope that's right!
}

/* If you've got a truly old version of Java, you can omit these
two next methods. */
private synchronized void writeObject(final ObjectOutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
    // just so we're synchronized.
    out.defaultWriteObject();
}

private synchronized void readObject(final ObjectInputStream in)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // just so we're synchronized.
    in.defaultReadObject();
}

/** This method is missing from jdk 1.0.x and below.  JDK 1.1
includes this for us, but what the heck.*/
public boolean nextBoolean() {
    return next(1) != 0;
}

/** This generates a coin flip with a probability <tt>probability</tt>
of returning true, else returning false. <tt>probability</tt> must
be between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.  Not as precise a random real
event as nextBoolean(double), but twice as fast. To explicitly
use this, remember you may need to cast to float first. */
public boolean nextBoolean(final float probability) {
    if (probability < 0.0f || probability > 1.0f) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("probability must be between 0.0"
                + " and 1.0 inclusive.");
    }
    if (probability == 0.0f) {
        return false;            // fix half-open issues
    } else if (probability == 1.0f) {
        return true;        // fix half-open issues
    }
    return nextFloat() < probability;
}

/** This generates a coin flip with a probability <tt>probability</tt>
of returning true, else returning false. <tt>probability</tt> must
be between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive. */
public boolean nextBoolean(final double probability) {
    if (probability < 0.0 || probability > 1.0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("probability must be between 0.0"
                + " and 1.0 inclusive.");
    }
    if (probability == 0.0) {
        return false;             // fix half-open issues
    } else if (probability == 1.0) {
        return true; // fix half-open issues
    }
    return nextDouble() < probability;
}

/** This method is missing from JDK 1.1 and below.  JDK 1.2
includes this for us, but what the heck. */
public int nextInt(final int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >= 0");
    }

    if ((n & -n) == n) {
        return (int) ((n * (long) next(31)) >> 31);
    }

    int bits, val;

    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);
    return val;
}

/** This method is for completness' sake.
Returns a long drawn uniformly from 0 to n-1.  Suffice it to say,
n must be > 0, or an IllegalArgumentException is raised. */
public long nextLong(final long n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be >= 0");
    }

    long bits, val;

    do {
        bits = (nextLong() >>> 1);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n - 1) < 0);
    return val;
}

/** A bug fix for versions of JDK 1.1 and below.  JDK 1.2 fixes
this for us, but what the heck. */
public double nextDouble() {
    return (((long) next(26) << 27) + next(27))
            / (double) (1L << 53);
}

/** A bug fix for versions of JDK 1.1 and below.  JDK 1.2 fixes
this for us, but what the heck. */
public float nextFloat() {
    return next(24) / ((float) (1 << 24));
}

/** A bug fix for all versions of the JDK.  The JDK appears to
use all four bytes in an integer as independent byte values!
Totally wrong. I've submitted a bug report. */
public void nextBytes(final byte[] bytes) {
    for (int x = 0; x < bytes.length; x++) {
        bytes[x] = (byte) next(8);
    }
}

/** For completeness' sake, though it's not in java.util.Random.  */
public char nextChar() {
    // chars are 16-bit UniCode values
    return (char) (next(16));
}

/** For completeness' sake, though it's not in java.util.Random. */
public short nextShort() {
    return (short) (next(16));
}

/** For completeness' sake, though it's not in java.util.Random.  */
public byte nextByte() {
    return (byte) (next(8));
}

/** A bug fix for all JDK code including 1.2.  nextGaussian can theoretical
 * ly
ask for the log of 0 and divide it by 0! See Java bug
<a href="http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/bugParade/bugs/4254501.h
 * tml">
http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/bugParade/bugs/4254501.html</a>
 */
synchronized public double nextGaussian() {
    if (__haveNextNextGaussian) {
        __haveNextNextGaussian = false;
        return __nextNextGaussian;
    } else {
        double v1, v2, s;

        do {
            v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1.0 and 1.0
            v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1; // between -1.0 and 1.0
            s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
        double multiplier = /* Strict*/ Math.sqrt(-2
                * /* Strict*/ Math.log(s) / s);

        __nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
        __haveNextNextGaussian = true;
        return v1 * multiplier;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: class `MersenneTwister extends java.util.Random` is the same like using Random

Comment: Have you read the question? I don't want to initialize any class.

Comment: it overrides the methods from Random. It calls all the way down to System.currentTimeMillis()

You can back track the organization of the classes and methods to get down to the System.currentTimeMillis() call, but I figured you rather having something to look at then nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default random method in [java.lang.math](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29).

It returns a double between 0.0 and 1.0 (0.0 <= n < 1.0).

You can do some simple tricks to convert this to various random values:

```
boolean coinFlip = (Math.random() >= 0.5);
int card = (int)(Math.random() * 52);
```

However, this makes a new java.util.Random() behind the scenes, which I think you are trying to avoid.

If you don't want to use any library, then you have to make your own implementation, which will probably end up being much more complicated.

You mentioned using time, this could certainly work for generating numbers, but for any practical purpose it is not really random.  Something like:

```
long betweenOneAndTen = 1 + (System.currentTimeMillis() % 10);
```

Comment: I ended up with a solution. Whay do you think?

Comment: Yup, that looks right.  If you want something a little more advanced, you can take Hot Licks' suggestion of using a hash function rather than a simple modulo.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Math.random()` function, you are neiter making a dependence on the `Random` class nor initializing anything (at least it's not your responsibility). There is no fundamental difference between calling `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `System.nanoTime()` and `Math.random()`---except that the latter is more performant and better at returning a random value.

Comment: How `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` generates random numbers !? the values will be 100% correlated when sampled at fixed time step, which should not be the case with `Math.random()`

Comment: @iTech Why don't you ask OP that :) My claim is that `Math.random()` is **better** than those two at generating random numbers. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, just I did not understand when you said *There is no fundamental difference between calling ...*; that's why I asked :)

Comment: @iTech I'm trying to respond to OP's requirement not to depend on `Random` or initialize anything, yet it's apparently OK to call other static methods from the standard library.